# GnuPG implementations are not cross-compatible?

Tags: encryption, pgp

Let's say I made my private key using Enigmail. Then I imported it into a Windows program called [GPG4USB](http://gpg4usb.cpunk.de/). When I want to decrypt a message it asks for my encryption password but it doesn't accept the password I provided with Enigmail originally. Both software are derivatives of GnuPG. Am I understanding it correctly that different implementations are not compatible with each other or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your question is off-topic here, since it isn't about security, it's about using Gpg4usb and Enigmail. You could ask this question on [su], but be sure to give more information, because as asked here the question is not answerable. For a start, you talk about making a private key, but then decrypting with a password: which one is it? Explain exactly how you configured the programs and exactly what you did to create and attempt to decrypt the message.

Answer (score 1):

*Someone* is doing something wrong, but not necessarily you. GnuPG follows the [OpenPGP format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), which is a standard.

The format includes provisions for using several cryptographic algorithms; not all implementations support all of them. However, GnuPG tends to implement the same algorithms as... itself.

The usual suspect for password interoperability issues is *encoding*: passwords are *characters* but must be converted to *bytes* in order to do cryptography with them. If you have a non-ASCII character in your password, it is possible that one front-end used [latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (or a superset such as [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)) while the other preferred [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), resulting in a distinct sequence of bytes for the same password. Even with ASCII, you can get issues with [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), which is not ASCII-compatible.